# yii2 любое количество get параметров

Tags: php, yii2

Сейчас я в urlManager прописываю все хардкором.

```
'art/list' => 'ask/index',
'art/list/sort/<sort:\w+>/' => 'ask/index',
'art/list/sort/<sort:\w+>/type/<type>' => 'ask/index',
```

И ссылка выходит такого вида:

```
/art/list/sort/new/type/pro+local+buisnes+tourist
```

Как можно сделать так что б каждый параметр не прописывать в urlManager каждый раз к примеру если у меня их будет 10 и больше?